# How can I persist a form if I am using an API to validate the data?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

Normally, if I use CakePHP's magic and validate forms then it would "persist the form" which would mean the user wouldn't have to re-input everything. Also, CakePHP by default marks all the fields that failed the validation. My question is, since I am sending all the form data to an API, how can I still use the all of CakePHP's magic?

I looked into custom validation methods, but the problem is that I have to send all the data to the API at once and I'll get all the errors back at once (Billing information).

Answer (score 0):

then you are doing it wrong.
the default "cake" way is to persist the form - even (or especially) after an unsuccessful validation

without seeing actual code one cannot tell you anything more, though.
check out the bake templates and how it is done correctly.
then your question resolves itself immediately.

Comment: Thanks. Actually the thing is, the validation is sending the data to the API and seeing if it fails. Is there a way to "persist" the form if I use the API for error checking?

Comment: @Strawberry you're talking about some kind of API? What is this, could you explain more? If there is something custom in between the Cake Core and your external application the middle layer could be handling validation responses differently that you would expect.

Comment: Its nothing that complicated. I'm just sending billing information to a payment gateway, and then getting a response. I just want to know how can I do this while still utilizing all the magic of CakePHP.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you set $this->request->data from database after false validation? Retrieve Model data only on GET request. Use this from Blog tutorial:

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    $this->Post->id = $id;
    if ($this->request->is('get')) {
        $this->request->data = $this->Post->read();
    } else {
        if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been updated.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to update your post.');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using an api to test a single field then write a custom validator for your model that calls that api method. If your api is validating the entire model or multiple fields you might be able to do a

$this->Model->set($this->data); 
if($this-Model->validates()) {
      /* Call Api */
       if errors
      /* Set $this-Model->validationErrors in same format as cake validation would have done. 
       else redirect to success page. 
}